# Unable to solve nonlinear equation in Fourier space

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, fft

I am using scipy.optimize.fsolve to solve a nonlinear equation in Fourier pseudospectral space but it does not work. It gives the same output as the input u0. The equation I am trying to solve is:

[image: equation]

The code is given below. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

M = 16
nu = 0.4

def kssol(M):

    kkx = np.fft.fftfreq(2*M)*2.*M

    kx = kkx[0:M+1]

    def func(vec):

         linspec = -(kx**2)+(nu*(kx**4))
         lin = linspec*np.fft.rfft(vec)
         nlin = np.zeros_like(lin)
         nlinre = vec*vec
         nlin = 0.5*1j*kx*np.fft.rfft(nlinre)   
         sol = lin+nlin
         rhs = np.zeros_like(sol, dtype='complex')
         sol -= rhs

        return np.fft.irfft(sol)

    u0 = np.zeros((2.*M,))
    u = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, u0) 

    return u
```

Comment: Change `u = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, u0) ` to `u, info, ier, msg = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, u0, full_output=True)`.  Then check the value of `ier` after the call.  If it is not 1, print `msg` to see what went wrong.

Comment: I checked the value of `ier` is 1 and `msg` says The solution is converged. But still the output value is the same as input `u0`.

Comment: Your initial guess for `fsolve` is an array of zeros.  The constant function `u(x) = 0` is a solution to your equation.

Comment: Yes that is right. But `u(x)=0` is a trivial solution. Is there any other way to get the non-trivial solution?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Can you suggest any other way of obtaining a non-trivial solution?

Comment: Note that any constant is also a solution.  To find different solutions you could try nontrivial values for `u0`.  Your equation is a fourth order ordinary differential equation, so you could also use an ODE solver instead of the pseudo-spectral method.  Different initial conditions in an initial value problem solver will give you different solutions.